# I want Generate same name variables with different datatype in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I want Generate  same name variables with different datatype in C#

```
[DataContract]
public class Segments2
{
    // List<Segments<string, IEnumerable<string>>>{ get; set; }
    //public object Segments { get; set; }   

    //public dynamic Segments { get; set; }      
  //  public List<Segments> Segment { get; set; }
    // public  IEnumerable<Segments> Segments { get; set; }
      //[DataMember(Name= "Segments")]

     [DataMember(Name = "Segments")]
     public Segments Segmen { get; set; }

     [DataMember(Name="Sagements" namespace= b)]
     public List<Segments> Segments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: this is impossible. Class members should have unique names in C#.

Comment: Could you please format your question as a question?

Comment: I fear that is not possible. How should the compiler know which one you are using?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? Where is the Json you want to parse? Do you *really* have two Json strings where `Segments` is a dictionary in one case but an array in the next? Also why are you posting a DataContract class? This is only used in XML serialization and the older, deprecated JsonDataContractSerializer. Everyone is using JSon.NET these days

Comment: sorry am not using Datacontract  my class struct is like this  i have use in class two different datatypes same variable name  one is list another one is object i dont much idea on json .net please shared it

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible. How should you or the compiler know which variable are you using.